# Could not load type "acme_user_registration" FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

Using the default instructions here:

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

to setup a custom "name" field in my registration form works great.

I want two fields for name. One for First name and another for Last name. So first I just wanted to override the name field to First name. By changing the Entity to First name causes this error:

```
Could not load type "acme_user_registration"
```

Why does it blow up when I've simply changed the column title? Ive added getters/setters also. I think it is an issue with the services.xml, but I don't know how services works with the yml settings and Form Builder.

**User.php**

```
     /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max="255",
     *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     */
    protected $firstname;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
```

**RegistrationFormType.php**

```
<?php

namespace MACP\CmsBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;

class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        // add your custom field
        $builder->add('firstname');
    }

    public function getFirstname()
    {
        return 'acme_user_registration';
    }
}
```

**services.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
        <service id="acme_user.registration.form.type" class="MACP\CmsBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType">
            <tag firstname="form.type" alias="acme_user_registration" />
            <argument>%fos_user.model.user.class%</argument>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

**config.yml**

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: MACP\CmsBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: acme_user_registration
```

Comment: Sounds like services.xml did not get loaded. Did you include it in config?

Comment: Hmmm, well it works when the Entity variable is set to name. How would I include it in the config.yml? Something like....imports:
    - { resource: services.xml }

Comment: Something like that. Did you try it? And does getName return 'acme_user_registration'; like getFirstname does?

Comment: Adding the import to the config.yml did not work. I am confused about what I am actually doing with return 'acme_user_registration'. It seemed to return correctly when it was getName, possibly not when it's getFirstName. Could this be something with DependencyInjection?

Comment: Ok I got it. It was not a services issue, of DI. I thought getName was using the getter from the entity. I "think" it's getting the name from services.xml. So if I keep the public function getName as it is in the tut is works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to change method:

```
public function getFirstname()
{
    return 'acme_user_registration';
}
```

to:

```
public function getName()
{
    return 'acme_user_registration';
}
```

This method tell you how exactly this form is called. And then you use this name in configuration. The rest looks just fine for me, but we will try.

Comment: Can you expound a little further on what getName does? Off the cuff, it appears like a getter, but it looks like it controls the tag in services. I think this would help further explain the functionality.

Comment: I guess that's a big fat no.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed your comment. Yes, indeed it controls the name of form, but I'm not sure if we can call it as a service's tag. Generally, form builder is getting and building forms by this name.

Comment: Ok, that explains it a bit more. Thanks